# highcharts opacity when "bubbles" are stacked

Tags: css, highcharts, opacity, overlap, bubble-chart

I have a problem regarding opacity(transparency) with highcharts in my case bubble chart and i think i can explain it best with an example

Example: i have a series with 100 bubbles that cover each other in the chart and the opacity is set to 1% (0.01). My problem here is shouldn't all the bubbles that are over each other have an opacity of 100%  (1) or is my knowlage of how opacity works wrong?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart:{
            type:'bubble'
        },        
        series: [{
            name: '1',
            data: [{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}                 
                  ],
            marker:{
                fillOpacity:0.01,
                lineWidth:0,
                fillColor:'#000000'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/kte3omhg/1/

And if there is a work around this problem i would appreciate it if someone posts it

**Edit**: Okey i found out that opacity doesn't work as i thought it would

```
Total Opacity = First Opacity + (100 - First Opacity) * Second Opacity
              = 0.7 + (1 - 0.7) * 0.7
              = 0.7 + (0.3) * 0.7
              = 0.7 + 0.21
              = 0.91
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_opacity

But i would still like to know if there is a solution to getting my result

Comment: what is the result you're actually looking for? And what are you trying to actually do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could use:

1. Using the opacity the way it is

   1.1. Keep `fillOpacity`, but vary the `# of elements`:

   - Keeping the `fillOpacity: 0.01`:
   - How many elements it is necessary to get a resultant `0.99` opacity?

   > ```
   > function calculateTimes(opacity, overlappingOpacity) {
   >     var times = 1;
   >     var currentOpacity = opacity;
   >     while (currentOpacity < overlappingOpacity) {
   >         currentOpacity += (1 - currentOpacity) * opacity;
   >         times++;
   >     }
   >     return times;
   > }
   > calculateTimes(0.01, 0.99); //Gives you 459 elements
   > ```

   [Fiddle for `459` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/n8dLfuaq/1/)

   1.2. Keep the `# of elements`, but vary `fillOpacity`

   - Keeping the 100 elements:
   - How much should `fillOpacity` be set to get a resultant `0.99` opacity?

   > ```
   > function calculateOverlappedOpacity(opacity, times) {
   >     return times == 1 ? opacity : opacity + (1 - opacity) * calculateOverlappedOpacity(opacity, times - 1);
   > }
   >
   > function calculateOpacityFor(resultantOpacity, times) {
   >     for (var i = 0.0001; i <= 1; i += 0.0001) {
   >         if (calculateOverlappedOpacity(i, times) >= resultantOpacity) {
   >             return i;
   >         }
   >     }
   >     return 1;
   > }
   > calculateOpacityFor(0.99, 100) //Gives you a fillOpacity of 0.0451
   > ```

   [Fiddle for `fillOpacity: 0.0451`](http://jsfiddle.net/u263ad3d/)
2. Using the opacity the way you thought it worked

   - Use 1 element set with a desired `fillOpacity` based on the element quantity:
   - How much should the resultant opacity be (based on the quantity of elements)?

   > ```
   > 0.01 * chartData.length
   > ```

   [Fiddle for a simulation of the expected opacity algorithm](http://jsfiddle.net/29zntgzo/1/)